# SQL Server linux forwarding

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, forwarding, mssql-jdbc

I'm wondering if I could forward SQL queries from localhost to another local IP address?

I don't want to install SQL Server on Linux, but I need to connect to it on another PC through localhost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use iptables:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -s localhost -d x.x.x.x --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

where x.x.x.x is the mysql server ip address, and eth0 is the interface you use.

Comment: Thanks! But I use firewalld. I tried this command firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=1433:proto=tcp:toaddr=192.168.1.110. And it didn't work. The sql client always says Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking if you are on a Linux machine you want to query to localhost and have that query forwarded to a SQL Server. In this case the above answer is partially correct and will allow packets to be forwarded but doesn't actually perform the forward/redirect. You also say "SQL Server" which I take to mean MS SQL Server. The default port in this case is listed as 1433. You would actually need (2) rules:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i lo -d localhost --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x # where x.x.x.x is the SQL Server IP address
# iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -p tcp --dport -j ACCEPT # only if your default FORWARD policy is DROP. Otherwise you just need the prerouting rule.
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Thanks! But I use firewalld. I tried this command firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=1433:proto=tcp:toaddr=192.168.1.110. And it didn't work. The sql client always says Connection refused.

Comment: Most likely because the 'lo' interface doesn't tend to belong to any firewalld zones. It looks like your code may have been based on an internet example. Is your default zone 'external' (`firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`)? If not it won't match for interface 'lo'. If you have a different default zone (e.g. public) use that zone instead of 'external' in your above command.

Comment: Doesn't work anyway. Can't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: From this client can you connect directly to the SQL Server?

Comment: It turns out there's some weirdness with how localhost packets traverse the IPTables system. See this link for a couple solutions:
https://serverfault.com/questions/616275/how-do-i-forward-localhost-traffic-to-a-remote-host-with-iptables

Comment: Yes I can connect using server IP address